# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... how to update an AUTO INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `feeds` (
 `FEED_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `P_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `P_NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`P_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `FEED_ID` (`FEED_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

::

```
INSERT INTO `table_a` (`P_ID`,`P_NAME`) VALUES ('30','John') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `P_ID`= VALUES(`P_ID`),`P_NAME`= VALUES(`P_NAME`);
```

I would like to use INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
where anytime I create that insert, I'd like the FEED_ID to auto increment.
As for now it stays the same because there was no new row insertion...

Should I delete then insert?

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (\`BIZ_ID\`)` <- where is `BIZ_ID`?

Comment: Can you give an example showing some data of your table before and after an insert which triggers the ON DUPLICATE? It is not exactly clear, what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry @hjpotter92, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem like you're looking for [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`; it will remove the old row if one exists with a conflicting primary key or unique key, and insert a new one with a new `FEED_ID`;

```
REPLACE INTO feeds (p_id,p_name) VALUES (1,'Olle');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b72db/1).